Deriving an $f(k,n)$ giving the fraction of the hypervolume enclosed by the convex regular $n$-polytope with $k$ facets enclosed only by its insphere
Let $P$ be a convex regular polytope, whose insphere is an $n$-sphere with radius $R$
Define:

$\operatorname{Vol}(B^{n+1};R)$ denotes the hypervolume enclosed by the $n$-sphere of radius $R$
$\operatorname{Vol}(\partial B^{n+1};R)$ denotes the hypervolume of the boundary of the $(n+1)$-ball of radius $R$
$\operatorname{Vol}(P;R)$ denotes the hypervolume enclosed by the polytope $P$ whose insphere is the $n$-sphere of radius $R$
$\operatorname{Vol}(\Sigma f_i;R)$ denotes the total hypervolume summed over every facet of the polytope $P$ whose insphere is the $n$-sphere of radius $R$

In the special case where $P$ is a regular polygon with an incircle of radius $R$, it's easy to check that
$$\frac{\operatorname{Vol}(B^2;R)}{\operatorname{Vol}(P;R)}=\frac{\pi}{k}\cot(\frac{\pi}{k})=\frac{\operatorname{Vol}(\partial B^2;R)}{\operatorname{Vol}(\Sigma f_i;R)}$$
where $k$ is the number of sides that the regular polygon has, and $R$ is of course the inradius (apothem) of the regular polygon
Question
What I want to know how to derive is an expression $f(k,n)$ - where $k$ is the number of facets of the polytope and $n$ is the dimension of the polytope - such that
$$\frac{\operatorname{Vol}(B^{n+1};R)}{\operatorname{Vol}(P;R)}=f(k,n)=\frac{\operatorname{Vol}(\partial B^{n+1};R)}{\operatorname{Vol}(\Sigma f_i;R)}$$

What I've thought about so far:
According to the section of the Wikipedia entry on the $n$-sphere about volume and area,
$$\frac{\operatorname{Vol}(\partial B^{n+1};R)}{\operatorname{Vol}(B^{n+1};R)}=\frac{2\Gamma(\frac{n+3}{2})}{R\Gamma(\frac{n+1}{2})}$$ $\tag1$
In addition, I have an unproven conjecture due to a pattern I've noticed, which is that
$$\operatorname{Vol}(\Sigma f_i;R)=\frac{\partial}{\partial R}(\operatorname{Vol}(P;R))$$
This conjecture can easily be checked to hold in the case of $n=1$ (where the insphere is a $1$-sphere), because
$$\operatorname{Perimeter of polygon with k sides}=\operatorname{Vol}(\Sigma f_i;R)=2k\tan(\frac{\pi}{k})R=\frac{\partial}{\partial R}(k\tan(\frac{\pi}{k})R^2)$$ $$=\frac{\partial}{\partial R}(\operatorname{Vol}(P;R))=\frac{\partial}{\partial R}(\operatorname{Area of polygon with k sides})$$

Reminder: $R$ is the inradius (apothem) of the regular polygon

Perhaps proving this conjecture for all convex $n$-dimensional regular polytopes would assist (when taken in conjunction with (1)) in deriving $f(k,n)$
Note that the expression $f(k,n)$ gives the fraction of the hypervolume enclosed by the polytope enclosed only by its insphere
Note as well that the expression $f(k,n)$ gives the ratio of the "surface hypervolume" of the insphere to the "surface hypervolume" of the polytope
Lastly, note that we should of course expect that $$\lim\limits_{k\rightarrow \infty} f(k,n)=1$$ regardless of the number of dimensions $n$

(Edit: this was a blunder on my part. In $n=2$ there are already only a finite number of platonic solids, so the limit is actually not well-defined. I got too carried away with only considering $n=1$)

and
$$f(k,1)=\frac{\pi}{k}\cot(\frac{\pi}{k})$$

You should be aware that for $convex\ regular$ polytopes there only is a finite amount of such if n is different from 1. Thence a limes on k does not make any sense on such a finite set.

@Dr.RichardKlitzing Oh and lastly, would you mind letting me know whether or not my conjecture is correct that
$\operatorname{Vol}(\Sigma f_i;R)=\frac{\partial}{\partial R}(\operatorname{Vol}(P;R))$
This conjecture can easily be checked to hold in the case of $n=1$ (where the insphere is a $1$-sphere), but I have no ideas on how to prove it in the general case.

For regular polytopes simply consider Vol(P,R) to be evaluated as sum of the all alike centri-pyramids, being based on the facets each. Note further that the volume of each such pyramid is proportional $R^n/n!$

Outside from the few low dimensions $D=1,...,4$ there are only 3 convex regular polytopes any longer, the simplex, the orthoplex, and the hypercube.
Furthermore, when considering the gamma function, which is related to the volume of the hyperball, it becomes clear that one always has to distinguish even and odd dimensions.
For even dimensions $D$ e.g. your requested ratios got already evaluated here:

V$_{simplex}(D)$ : V$_{in-hyperball}(D)$ = $\frac{\sqrt{\frac{D+1}{2^D}}}{D!}$ : $\left( \frac{π^D}{D!} · \frac1{\left(\sqrt{2D(D+1)}\right)^D} \right)$ = $\sqrt{D+1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{D(D+1)}}{π}\right)^D$,  $\ $ if $D = 2n$

V$_{orthoplex}(D)$ : V$_{in-hyperball}(D)$ = $\frac{\sqrt{2^D}}{D!}$ : $\left( \frac{π^D}{D!} · \frac1{\left(\sqrt{2D}\right)^D} \right)$ = $\left(\frac{2\sqrt{D}}{π}\right)^D$, $\ $ if $D = 2n$

V$_{hypercube}(D)$ : V$_{in-hyperball}(D)$ = $1$ : $\left( \frac{π^D}{D!} · \frac1{2^D} \right)$ = $\left(\frac2{π}\right)^D D!$, $\ $ if $D = 2n$


In all 3 cases, when considering increasing dimensions $D$, all those values increase without bound. Thus, the most of the respective polytopal volumes will ultimately be located outside of their respective in-hyperballs!
--- rk

That is a rather surprising result about the strangeness of higher dimensions. Very interesting!
